# I got lost in my game, How can I return back? (unreal engine)

Tags: unreal-engine4

So I fell out of the world, and now I am lost in my own world because I can't find the map again. How can I return back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select any of your scene objects on "World Outliner" tab and press Shift+F to center view on this object.